# how is it possible that an inverter absorb reactive power

Tags: power, power-electronics, inverter, reactive-power

It's always said that reactive power is interpreted as magnetic field in motors (or transformers) it can also be the electric field in capacitor, but where does an inverter "store" that reactive energy?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, the inverter doesn't store the energy, it dissipates the energy by delivering it to an external load.

Comment: You have the answer in your question. Power isn't energy. Reactive power doesn't add up to energy over time because it's shifted in and out during one phase cycle.

Comment: there is always a magnetic energy or electric one, when it doesn't go out the circuit it's a reactive energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a physical stock of reactive energy, but the control imposes a phase shift between voltage and current, which means a power factor lower than 1.

Answer (score 2):

### Power and energy

First, I think it's important to be clear about terms.  The question seems to 
be using the terms *power* and *energy* as though they were synonyms and they are definitely not.  A 60W incandescent light bulb is marked 60W because that's how much power it uses.  If we leave such a bulb on for one hour, we will have used 60Wh (60 watthours).  (One watthour is 3600 joules, if you prefer SI units.)

So *energy* is essentially *power* integrated over *time*.  Energy can be stored (as in a battery) but power cannot in the same way that some volume of water can be stored (a bucket might hold 12 liters of water) but a rate of flow cannot (how many liters/minute does a bucket hold?  The question makes no sense!)

### Real and reactive

[image]

As this diagram shows, the relationship between real and reactive quantities (power in this case) is that they can be thought of as two non-hypotenuse legs of a right triangle.  The angle \$\varphi\$ is the power factor angle and \$\cos \varphi\$ = power factor.  If the *voltage* and *current* are exactly in phase as with a purely resistive circuit, the power factor is 1.0 and the reactive power is 0.  If the voltage and current are exactly 90 degrees out of phase as with a purely inductive or purely capacitive circuit, the real energy component is 0 and the power factor is 0.0.

At any phase angle between those, we have both real and reactive components.

### Reactive energy

In the same way that we can think of real energy being stored in a battery, it's useful to think of reactive energy as being stored within the electric field of a capacitor or the magnetic field of an inductor, as you've noted.  To the degree that any circuit shifts the phase of the current with respect to the voltage (and obviously this can only apply to AC circuits), its *impedance* is said to have a reactive component.  So any circuit, including an inverter, that has an inductive or capacitive component to its impedance is temporarily storing reactive energy in one or more of its components.  An inverter often has a transformer as part of the circuit that attaches to an AC input and so is often an inductive load from the view of the power company.

Comment: Very nice and detailed answer, @Edward, specially the reactive part. Can you also provide some references?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the drawing below. In order to accommodate an inductive load, an inverter must have a capacitor with enough capacitance to store the energy received from the load during one half-cycle of the output waveform. The inverter switching elements must have anti-parallel diodes to carry current in the direction opposing the current from the DC supply.

The current between the DC supply and capacitor combination to the H-Bridge inverter will be DC with some AC ripple current. The ripple current is the reactive component of the current in the load it transfers energy back and forth between the inductance of the load and the capacitance in the inverter.

[image]

Comment: In addition, the correspondence between the wave of the current and that of the voltage is a parameter expressed by the cosine phi, this parameter expresses the fact that two "substences" are not present at the same time the greater the phase shift plus the voltage And the current does not coincide